# Python: Joining sets of data based on Primary key combinations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to merge three dataframes based on the primary keys and leave the empty values as it is. This is how my dataframes is,

```
df1
col1 col2 cola colb
123  abc  JNT  80
123  abc  MTN  82
124  de   KTU  90

df2
col1 col2 colc  cold
123  abc  testa vala
124  de   test2 val2
124  de  test3 val3

df3
col1 col2 cole
123  abc  data1
```

This is the logic i have tried.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[123,123,124],'col2':['abc','abc','de'],'cola':['JNT','MTN','KTU'],'colb':[80,82,90]})
df2=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[123,124,124],'col2':['abc','de','de'],'colc':['testa','test2','test3'],'cold':['vala','val2','val3']})
df3=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[123],'col2':['abc'],'cole':['data1']})
cols=['col1','col2']
df=[df1,df2,df3]
df_final=pd.DataFrame()
for f in range(len(df)):    
    df[f]=df[f].set_index(cols)
df_final=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
print (df_final)

   col1 col2 cola  colb  col1 col2   colc  cold   col1 col2   cole
0   123  abc  JNT    80   123  abc  testa  vala  123.0  abc  data1
1   123  abc  MTN    82   124   de  test2  val2    NaN  NaN    NaN
2   124   de  KTU    90   124   de  test3  val3    NaN  NaN    NaN
```

But I need final output like this

```
col1  col2  cola  colb  colc  cold  cole
123   abc   JNT   80    testa vala  data1
123   abc   MTN   82
124   de                test2  val2
124   de                test3  val3
```

Can someone please help me.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: If you are new - refer to this document showing all types of joins in python. 
https://datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/05-merging-data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i said you need `cumcount` create the help key

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
df1['help'] = df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()
df2['help'] = df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()
df3['help'] = df3.groupby(cols).cumcount()

out = pd.concat(([x.set_index(cols+['help'])for x in [df1,df2,df3]]),axis=1).reset_index(level=[0,1])
out
Out[13]: 
      col1 col2 cola  colb   colc  cold   cole
help                                          
0      123  abc  JNT  80.0  testa  vala  data1
1      123  abc  MTN  82.0    NaN   NaN    NaN
0      124   de  KTU  90.0  test2  val2    NaN
1      124   de  NaN   NaN  test3  val3    NaN
```

Comment: BEN !!! whatever the logic you have used, i included that in my code. But It isnt working

Comment: This is how my datasets is, First Dataset : 4 rows Second Datset : 10 rows Third Dataset: 6 rows. All three datasets is having combination of 7 columns of primary keys. Actually in the end it should be only max dataset rows which is 10. But I could see 20 rows.

Comment: @Jennie What you mean can you show more detail , I think your sample data dose address the real problem you have